# Making a Function file that calls a function from another file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I have this gaussian2 m file:

```
function [g] = gaussian2(t, tau)
g = (1/sqrt(2*pi)) .*(1/tau) .* exp(- (t .^2) / (2 * tau^2));
end
```

I want to make another function m file of RMStau:

```
sqrt( integral( @(t) t.^2 .* gaussian2(t,tau), -inf, inf ) / integral( @(t) gaussian2(t,tau), -inf, inf ))
```

How do I make a RMStau m file as a function of my gaussian2 input?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Just put RMSTau inside a function, same structure as the first one.

Comment: This is what i did:


`function [anstau] = RMStau(z) 
b = @(t,tau) z;
anstau = sqrt( integral( @(t) t.^2 .* b(t,tau), -inf, inf ) / integral( @(t) b(t,tau), -inf, inf ));
end`


I want to be able to run this `RMStau(gaussian(t,5.5))`; the answer would be equal to `5.5`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it like this

```
@(t) gaussian2(t, 5.5)
```

And then use it as `z(t)` inside of RMStau since it only expects one argument t.

Another way is to use `varargin`, which allows you to pass any additional arguments to internal functions. So then you would do

```
function [anstau] = RMStau(z, varargin)
    anstau = sqrt( quad( @(t) t.^2 .* z(t, varargin{:}), -inf, inf ) / quad( @(t) z(t, varargin{:}), -inf, inf ));
end
```

and you could call it with `RMStau(@(t, tau) gaussian2(t, tau), 5.5)`. The reason you might want to use `varargin` is that you could also pass the function using a name instead a function handle. Then it would look like this

```
function [anstau] = RMStau(z, varargin)
    anstau = sqrt( quad( @(t) t.^2 .* feval(z, t, varargin{:}), -inf, inf ) / quad(@(t) feval(z, t, varargin{:}), -inf, inf ));
end
```

and both `RMStau(@(t, tau) gaussian2(t, tau), 5.5)` and `RMStau('gaussian2', 5.5)` would work.